# This dependency was not found in node_modules dependency

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue.js project *A* which I want to reuse in another Vue.js project *B*.

They have pretty similar setup: Vue.js + Typescript

I try to import components from *A* to *B*. What I do:

1. Add *A* project as git submodule to *B*
2. Add npm dependency to *A* project*
3. Import component from this npm dependency

This component uses some utils from the *A* project in this way:

```
import { func } from '@/utils/functions';
```

*A* project has specified *paths* option in *tsconfig.json*:

```
"paths": {
        "@/*": [
            "src/*"
        ]
    }
```

When I start the *B* app I get an error that says:

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/utils/functions
```

It seems like relative paths specified in this way (`@/`) is not resolved in node_modules.

So, how should I define the tsconfig.json in *B* project to resolve this dependency for my imported component? Or is there any other way to do what I described above (maybe something about webpack configs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in webpack config try something like that

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            }
        },
    }
}
```